# Undefined property: Wizard::$cache during upgrade from 2.3.1 to 2.8.1

Tags: ee2, upgrade, ee2-upgrades

I am upgrading from 2.3.1 to 2.8.1. I have gone through all the initial documented upgrade steps. I am also running MSM, and I have upgraded these files as well.

The installer loads correctly, then when I click the "Go ahead and upgrade" link (I forget the exact wording) I get a blank page. With debug = 1 I get the following error details:

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: Wizard::$cache
Filename: database/DB_cache.php
Line Number: 49

( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in (...)/admin/codeigniter/system/database/DB_cache.php on line 49
Call Stack

1   {main}( )   ../index.php:0

2   require_once( '..../admin/codeigniter/system/core/CodeIgniter.php' )    ../index.php:235

3   Wizard->_remap( )   ../CodeIgniter.php:306

4   Wizard->_license( ) ../wizard.php:266

5   CI_DB_active_record->count_all_results( )   ../wizard.php:642

6   CI_DB_driver->query( )  ../DB_active_rec.php:1023

7   CI_DB_Cache->read( )    ../DB_driver.php:276

Answer (score 2):

In my old database config file (expressionengine/config/database.php), there was the setting

```
$db['expressionengine']['cache_on'] = TRUE;
```

I believe this setting is for db query caching, which is not recommended anymore anyway.

In any case, changing this setting to FALSE, or deleting it, solved the issue for me.